# Unable to compile amqpcpp, Make error

Tags: c++, makefile, amqp

I have an issue compiling amqpcpp on a centos virtual machine, But it works fine on my iMac.

when I am running make I get this error:

```
g++  -Wall -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -Iinclude/  -c -o src/AMQPExchange.o 
src/AMQPExchange.cpp src/AMQPExchange.cpp: In member function ‘void 
AMQPExchange::sendDeclareCommand()’: src/AMQPExchange.cpp:73: error: cannot convert ‘amqp_table_t’ 
to ‘amqp_boolean_t’ for argument ‘7’ to ‘amqp_exchange_declare_ok_t* 
amqp_exchange_declare(amqp_connection_state_t_*, amqp_channel_t,
amqp_bytes_t, amqp_bytes_t, amqp_boolean_t, amqp_boolean_t, amqp_boolean_t, amqp_boolean_t,
amqp_table_t)’

make: *** [src/AMQPExchange.o] Error 1
```

[Github Issue Url](https://github.com/akalend/amqpcpp/issues/38)

g++ version

```
g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)
```

Unfortunately, I do not know enough of C++ or make yet to fully understand the issue. It seems that the compiler is complaining about a type cast style conversion in the code, which is confusing as it works fine on the mac.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Edit: I have downloaded the latest version of amqpcpp on both machines and re-compiled them, with the same results.

Edit 2: I realised that I installed librabbitmq-c on my mac a couple of months ago, I've just updated it to the latest version and it compains of a similar error to the centos machine, It appears that amqpcpp is not compatible with the latest changes to the librabbitmq codebase. It seems that this particular commit causes the issue:

[Commit 2340b039f029f3b8101a164d3bcd547be1106906](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c/commit/2340b039f029f3b8101a164d3bcd547be1106906)

I am going to try and update the AmqpCpp codebase to apply a fix, will post a link to pull request if it works. Otherwise, using an earlier commit when checking out the code should allow it to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the cause and 2 (temporary) resolutions.

Option One.. pull the librabbitmq code before the breaking changes:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c
$ cd rabbitmq-c/
$ git checkout e1746f92585d59364fc48b6305ce25d7fc86c2a4
```

And then compile as normal. I have tested this method and it works fine for me. Keep an eye out for future update on the AMQPCpp github page so that you know when its safe to update to the latest version.

Option Two .. Update the AMQPCPP code:

AMQPExchange.cpp:

Un-comment line 69 so that it reads:

```
amqp_boolean_t autodelete = (parms & AMQP_AUTODELETE)   ? 1:0;
```

Change Line 73 so that it reads:

```
amqp_exchange_declare(*cnn, (amqp_channel_t) 1, exchange, exchangetype, passive, durable, autodelete, 0, args );
```

Then you should be able to compile without an error. BEWARE: there are more changes in the librabbitmq code than just this function, which is why I stated this is a temporary fix. The AMQPCpp project will need to be updated properly to reflect the most recent changes. This fix works for what I need it to, You may find some other functionality is broken.

I personally decided to use Option One and it's now working as expected.

Thanks